# jQuery caching with POST

Tags: jquery

Although I have set cache:false in a jQuery AJAX Post request, it does not add the extra randomg string. Is this because post does not cache?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RFC 2616](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html) states (in section 13) that POST requests should not be cached.

> Some HTTP methods MUST cause a cache to invalidate an entity. This is either the entity referred to by the Request-URI, or by the Location or Content-Location headers (if present). These methods are:
>
> ```
> - PUT
> - DELETE
> - POST
> ```

Comment: The problem is, it looks like IE does.