# jQuery, $.post() not accessing target url

Tags: php, javascript, json, jquery

In the code below there is a XMLHTTPRequest with the target url `test_location_jquery.php`, and this file is never accessed despite the success function being triggered. When run alone for testing `test_location_jquery.php` has worked successfully returning the JSON object as expected. Any idea as to how the success function could be triggered while the file is not accessed would be appreciated.

### JQUERY

```
<?php

    require_once '../meta/php/dbConn.php';

    $charlie_query = "";
    $charlie_result = "";

    $charlie_query = "
        SELECT  ud.user_id as 'id',
                concat(ud.last_name,', ',ud.first_name) as 'name'
        FROM    `user_detail` AS ud,
                `user_type` AS UT
        WHERE ud.user_type = ut.id
        AND ut.class IN ('charlie')
        AND ut.level IN (4)
        ORDER BY ut.class;
    ";
    $charlie_result = mysql_query($charlie_query);
    
    if(!(bool)$charlie_result){
        throw new Exception();
    }

?>

<html>
<head>

    <script src="../meta/js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="../meta/js/getXML_sir.js"></script>  -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#charlie').change(function(){
                var charlie_id =  $('#charlie option:selected').val();
                var DT = "json";

                $.post(
                        'test_location_jquery.php',
                        {'id':charlie_id,'datatype':DT},
                        function(data){
                            alert('Success');
                            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                        }
                );
                
                if(obj != 'undefined'){
                    var locations = obj.find('location');
                    console.log(locations);
                }else{
                    alert("failure");
                }

            })
        })
            
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <label>Charlie: </label><select id="charlie" name="charlie">
            <option>&nbsp;</option>
        <?php
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($charlie_result)){
                print("<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['name']."</option>");
            } 
        ?>
        </select>
        <label>Location: </label><select id="location" name="location"></select>
    </form>
    
    <div></div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

### test_location_jquery.php

```
<?php

require_once("../meta/php/dbConn.php");

if(!isset($_POST)){
    throw new Exception();
}else{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $datatype = $_POST['datatype'];
}

$query = "
        SELECT  l.id as 'id',
            ld.attribute_string as 'name'
        FROM    `location` AS l,
                `location_details` AS ld
        WHERE l.id = ld.location_id
        AND     ld.attribute_label = 'name'
        AND l.id = ".$id.";
";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if(!(bool)$result){
    throw new Exception();
}else{
    switch($datatype){
        case 'xml':
        break;
        case 'json':
            $rows = array();
            while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $rows[] = $r;
            }
            return json_encode($rows);
        break;
}


?>
```

Comment: In your first code sample, you're testing if (obj != undefined) below the ajax call. The ajax call is asynchronous, so chances are, you'll get an alert("failure") before the ajax call's success function is executed. How do you know that the test_location_jquery.php file isn't being accessed?

Comment: I have included some code into test_location_query.php that writes to a file for any number of reasons. Mostly I was using it to watch the progress when the file was accessed, but the file has never been altered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `.post()` function is asynchronous.  That means that calling `.post()` just STARTs the post.  The lines following it execute immediately before the `post()` has completed and before the success handler is called.

Then, some time later the success handler is called.

All code that uses the response from the post MUST be in the success handler or called from the success handler.

So, your problem is that you cannot refer to data set in the success handler where this code is located (right after the `.post()` call).  You have to put this code inside the success handler itself.

```
            if(obj != 'undefined'){
                var locations = obj.find('location');
                console.log(locations);
            }else{
                alert("failure");
            }
```

So, after doing that, your code would look like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#charlie').change(function(){
            var charlie_id =  $('#charlie option:selected').val();
            var DT = "json";

            $.post(
                    'test_location_jquery.php',
                    {'id':charlie_id,'datatype':DT},
                    function(data){
                        alert('Success');
                        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                        if(obj != 'undefined'){
                            var locations = obj.find('location');
                            console.log(locations);
                        }else{
                           alert("failure");
                        }
                    }
            );


        })
    })

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed and well explained answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
                     $.post(
                        'test_location_jquery.php',
                        {'id':charlie_id,'datatype':DT},
                        function(data){
                            alert('Success');
                            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                            if(obj != 'undefined'){
                             var locations = obj.find('location');
                                  console.log(locations);
                             }else{
                                alert("failure");
                             }
                        }
                );
```

As Ajax is asynchronous, the obj variable didn't exist until the page was totally called. so if you put inside the function(data) it will only proceed after the call is completely made, and the variable will now exist.

Comment: According to the jQuery docs for .post(), the results of that are never cached so cache busting is not an issue here.

Comment: POST, DELETE and PUT are never cached in any HTTP request. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592884/jquery-caching-with-post